Mechanics of DEX limit orders
I want to understand how limit orders work on DEXes, for example on Jupiter.
The question is: can I place a limit order in the order book and just wait for a sharp sale on the market? Will it be filled if the price drops for just a second, and then rises in the next second?
This works fine on CEX, but on dexes? I'm interested in the mechanics of limit orders.

This should work the same as on CEXs. Is there something that makes you think otherwise?
